# android listview - update existing values single row at a time

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Thanks all for making an effort to help..Here is my confusion.
I have a list view, 
I load data into it (3 columns of textview) from a file.
Each column points to a location on filesystem
User clicks a button to start,
application reads first row of the list box, updates a column stating it is working , then goes out on internet, connects to the server, does some work which may take few seconds to a minute...and then come back and tells the listview its done.
At this point list view updates the column that it update before the start and puts some text such is completed.
Then it moves to the next row and does the same.
At some point it may have more items which are visible currently. In that situation, it should load the next item which is there but not loaded/visible in the listview and perform all the tasks above and then scroll to the next invisible item.
It should do all this until all the items which are loaded initially in the array list are not completed.
I need some help on how to go about taking care of this....hope it makes some sense
[image]

My problem is that how to do this in automatic fashin so that listview is updated one item at a time..each row is a complete process in itself...Can't think of a way..If I use Async Task, then my knowledge is limited and have no understanding on how to update each row in listview in a loop using asyntask...I hope it all made some sense

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have a bad android design approach. First of all, it is not a good idea to launch the async task from the activity. If a config change happens and your activity is destroyed by the time the async task has finished updating any row, the activity UI wont be notified ence the row update button wont be updated.
What I would do:

1. Create a class called "loader" (for example) and move your async task there. Would be good idea to instantiate this class on your application class so you can share it as a singleton along your code (getApplication().getLoader()).
2. Create a register unregister interface callback on the loader, so that any listener can be notified when a row has finished updating. The rowUpdateFinished callback method should return the id of the row updated and anyother info you need from the task finished that you d like to notify to the listeners. Also, create a listener interface for instance RowUpdateFinishedListenerI .
3. In your activity get a reference to the loader class during onCreate() and then register to the loader during onResume() and DONT FORGET to unregister from the loader during onPause(). The activity must implement the RowUpdateFinishedListenerI.
4. Set an onClickListener to the start loading button so that when pressed it will perform loader.startLoading().
5. In your loader post execute method from the async task (when the task finishes) notify the listeners: call rowUpdatedFinished(int rowPosition)
6. Your activity, that will be listening for this event, will receive the update signal and then act accordingly: Activate your task finished button in your list view item (there is a commonly used method to update a single row by position id, google it) and then make the listview to scroll to the next position (notified row + 1).